describe the dataset schema including the relationship between fields, for example fields like country and city, country has distinct group of city
I have a example dataset describing the country and the cites in this country.
for example,
[ 
   { person:'tom', countryName: 'USA', cityName:'newyork' },
   { person:'lee', countryName: 'China', cityName:'beijing' },
    ....
]

I want to describe the dataset with data schema in a standard way ( maybe in jsonschema  ) and save this schema into the database like mongodb as below
[
    { name:'personName', type:'String' },
    { name:'countryName', type:'String', options:['USA,'CHINA'] },
    { name:'cityName', type:'String', options:['newYork','chicago','beijing'..] }
],

however it misses out the relationships between countryName and cityName since each country has a distinct group of cities as below
[ 
   { countryName: 'USA', children: [ 'newYork','chicago',... ],
   { countryName: 'China', children: ['beijing', 'shanghai',...],
    ....
].

how would I change my schema to link this relationships in a standard way, so that I can input this data schema to a UI generator, it can understand the relationship between countryName and cityName, and automatically generate a cascade dropdown filter that clicking a country will popup its own cities.

This sounds like more of a Mongo question than JSON Schema.  Can you update the tags, please?

Hi, @gregsdennis I think it is more about the design of the schema how to describe the data fields with relationship in a better way, concerning the storage, it can save into any db, just mongodb is my choice.

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design

https://youtu.be/bxw1AkH2aM4?si=sGcLMc1KRuWwN22v

Lots of patterns here too. https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/schema/tutorials/
